# Microsoft Team creation using REST API taking more time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using Standard Template to create a MSTeams Team that includes installing an app using 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams' REST API.

As it returns teamsasyncoperation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsasyncoperation?view=graph-rest-beta) I periodically hit the teamsasyncoperation that is in the location header to get the status.

The document mentions periodically check with more than 30 seconds interval.

It is too much time to wait. And now-a-days often I receive the response as 'notStarted' even after 20 minutes.

Why is MSTeams taking that long to create the team? Is there any best way to create the team (that includes install app,create a channel and add members) quickly within 10 seconds?

Does Microsoft provides any paid subscription to make the Team creation as higher priority and quicker?

Comment: This question looks like it would be more appropriately asked on the microsoft support website.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? I could able to create team using API. Can you please share the sample request body and from which region you are working.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Thank you. 
Our biggest concern is Team creation API is not consistant and throws 504 and 502 error that forces us to use exponential retry mechanisim .
Sometimes it is crating within 20 seconds and sometimes it is taking more that minutes. In a worst case we have experienced 20 minutes to create the Teams. 

 Our cloud server is located in Dallas.

Comment: request body
 `{
 'template@odata.bind': "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')",
    'displayName': teamName,
    'description': teamDesc,
    'visibility': 'Private',
    'memberSettings': {
  'allowCreateUpdateChannels': false,
  'allowDeleteChannels': false,
        'allowAddRemoveApps': false,
  'allowCreateUpdateRemoveTabs': false,
  'allowCreateUpdateRemoveConnectors': false
 },
    'installedApps': [{
  'teamsApp@odata.bind': `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps('${install_app_id}')`
 }]
}`

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams is used to create the Teams.
We use https://graph.microsoft.com/beta${locationHeader} to get the status of the Team creation. 
 To avoid rate limiting issue we have 2 seconds delay between every Microsoft Teams API calls. 
 
 Please provide best practices to overcome this issue.

Comment: @KumarTech, Thanks for the details. Currently we are facing this issue due to high latency - the timed out resulting in 503 but the request continued in the backend.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT  Thank you. Is the high latency issue is same for all type of tenant or it is happening only on MSTeams Developer Account ? Could you provide information on when this issue due to high latency could be resolved on Microsoft side ? Please consider this as high priority issue as we cannot tell the customer to wait for 20 minutes for create a Teams.

Comment: Yes, this is currently happening for 0.1 cases. and will be resolved from Microsoft side shortly.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Could you confirm that high latency issue is same for all type of tenants and please provide the timeline when we shall get a consistent behaviour ?

Comment: @KumarTech, Sorry for the delayed response. Latency issue can be for all type of tenant. But 20 minutes seems unusual. Can you please share your tenant id, requestid and time attempted. We could see logs for that request.

Comment: Thanks @Subhasish-MSFT We experienced  ~20 minutes delay around 30 days before. We will share the  required details once we experience ~5 minutes delay